# Как вычислить ускорение выполнения программы?

Tags: java, архитектура, железо, препроцессор

Подскажите пожалуйста по какой/каким формулам вычисляется ожидаемое ускорение выполнения программы.
Вроде как правильный ответ под буквой "б", но не могу сообразить как именно производятся вычисления. Не могу понять связь данныз значений

Некое приложение, написанное на языке Java, выполняется на настольном компьютере за 15 секунд. Новый выпуск компилятора Java требует только 0,6 инструкции, генерировавшейся старым компилятором. Но, к сожалению, он повышает показатель CPI в 1,1 раза. Каково ожидаемое ускорение выполнения программы при использовании нового компилятора? Выберите правильный ответ из трех приведенных ниже:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все довольно просто, раньше код тратил T1 на выполнение M1 инструкций стоимостью W1 каждая, т.е. M1 * W1 = T1. После изменений код стал тратить M2 = M1 * 0.6 инструкций стоимостью W2 = W1 * 1.1. Получается следующее:

```
T2 = M2 * W2 
T2 = (M1 * 0.6) * (W1 * 1.1)
T2 = (M1 * W1) * (0.6 * 1.1)
T2 = T1 * 0.6 * 1.1
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за чистые формулы. Теперь то все кажется довольно таки простым.